# Is Post's tag system solved?

Tags: reference-request, computability-theory, automata-theory

Has the 3-tag system investigated by Emil Post $(0\to00, 1\to1101)$ been solved? Is there a decision algorithm to determine which starting strings terminate, which end up in a cycle, and which (if any) grow without bound?

Also, what cycle structures are there? Setting $a=$ '00' and $b=$ '1101', the only cycles I know of begin with $ab, b^2 a^2$, combinations of these, and $a^2 b^3 (a^3 b^3)^n$. Are there any more?

Comment: Worth noting:  this is the 75th anniversary of the problem’s publication!  Post mentioned its intractability on p 204 of his 1943 article.  The bibliography to the Wikipedia article (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_System) has the citation to Post and quotes Minsky concurring in 1967.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the two irreducible repeating patterns that Liesbeth de Mol discovered, together with a third high-period irreducible repeating pattern discovered by Rich Schroeppel:

- $b^3 a^5 b^5$ (period 40);
- $a b^2 a b^3 a^3 b^3 a^2 b^2 a^4 b^2$ (period 66);
- $a b^3 a b a b a^2 b^2 a b^9 a^2$ (period 282);

This was discovered [by 2004](https://www.experimentalmath.info/workshop2004/schroeppel-talk.pdf), and as far as I know no other irreducible repeating patterns are known yet.

Answer (score 12):

**Q1:** The status of Post's 3-tag system as of 2011 was reviewed by Liesbeth de Mol in [On the complex behavior of simple tag systems. An experimental approach.](https://hal.univ-lille3.fr/hal-01396517/document) *"It is still not known whether this particular example has a decidable reachability problem."* [Citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?client=safari&rls=en&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=6491146449059987717) to this work through 2017 indicate that the situation has not changed since 2011.

**Q2:** Concerning cycle structures, De Mol found additional cycles:

> Let $a = 00$, $b = 1101$. Watanabe deduced wrongly that there are only four kinds of periodic
>   words in Post’s tag system, i.e., $a^2b^3(a^3b^3)^n$ with period 6, $ba$ with
>   period 2, $b^2a^2$ with period 4, or any concatenation of the last two. In
>   some preliminary runs on Post’s tag system we found three other kinds
>   of periodic words, a period 10, 40 and 66. The period 10 $(b^2a^3b^3a^2)$ is
>   similar to the periodic words found by Watanabe, the period 40 and 66
>   are very different from these periodic words.

Comment: The period 10 word is a combination of $b^2 a^2 $ and $ab$, so it's not technically a new periodic word

Comment: indeed, it's the period 40 and period 66 words which are different.